# Can Flex 4 or Actionscript access shared C or C++ library?

Tags: apache-flex, matlab, actionscript, shared-libraries, matlab-deployment

I'm having a Flex4/Actionscript application developed for access in a web browser. I need it to perform some math involving imaginary numbers (e.g. sqrt(-1)). I don't believe either Flex or Actionscript supports this.

However, I can put all of the math algorithms in a shared C or C++ library (as created by Matlab). Can Flex or Actionscript  access these algorithms (and run them on the client)? Any better way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Can Flex or Actionscript access these algorithms (and run them on the client)?
```

Sort of.  You can use [Alchemy](http://labs.adobe.com/technologies/alchemy/) to use C/C++ libraries in the Flash Player.  I'm not sure exactly how it works.  The project is experimental, but Adobe has announced they have a new version coming and that they will "commercialize" it.  I assume that means tools will be rolled into Flash Pro or Flash Builder.

This was the technology behind the 2011 Adobe Max Keynote that displayed a game made with the Unreal engine running a browser.

Some quick searching came up with this AS2 [library](http://members.shaw.ca/flashprogramming/wisASLibrary/wis/) which may help without going the C route.  ( [Source](http://board.flashkit.com/board/showthread.php?t=723964) ).  You'd probably want to convert it to AS3, but I would expect that to be minimal.

Comment: Keep in mind that you can only use a subset of c/c++ features with alchemy.
You will not be able to get out of the flash player sandbox for security reasons of course. This means that some file system features are disabled, etc...

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative to Alchemy you can use [FluorineFx Aperture Framework](http://aperture.fluorinefx.com/). It adds a feature to use `LocalConnection` to exchange data between AIR app and some sort of C++ dll. The advantage is that this dll is truly native, you can compile it in e.g. Visual Studio, use all the features of C++ without restrictions. The disadvantages are following: unreliable `LocalConnection`, limitation to use AIR, limitation to run on Windows only.

Another method we used on one of the projects is exchanging data between two separate applications: native and AIR, i.e. you have "server" application and "client" AIR. As "protocol" we simulated `LocalConnection` at first, but then switched to Windows Pipes as more stable. Another way is to use local sockets.

Comment: The FlourineFx Aperture project sounds, on paper, similar to Native Extensions.  Is the project still relevant?

Comment: As soon as the only support for NativeExtensions is in not yet released Flash Builder 4.6 - I think, it's relevant :) Actually, both features are quite similar.

Comment: I'm sorry.  I meant NativeProcess, not Native Extensions. But that said, Native Extensions are supported now via command line tools.

Comment: Thanks! How does the local sockets solution work? Pros/cons? (I wonder if it's practical to implement on client's computer). e.g. http://cote.cc/blog/opening-a-local-socket-from-an-swf-file

Comment: I haven't face the problem described in the link - the solution with sockets raised firewall warnings and security notifications about open port, so we decided to implement something else. Pros: reliability, notifications about new data (in case of pipes you should check for new data every N ms).